# Rails Value of type BSON::ObjectId cannot be written to a field of type Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Helo everyone,

I try to access a BSON Id with rails and mongoid, when I run a task, but I have this error message :

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidValue:
message:
  Value of type BSON::ObjectId cannot be written to a field of type Array
summary:
  Tried to set a value of type BSON::ObjectId to a field of type Array
resolution:
  Verify if the value to be set correspond to field definition
```

I don't understand why, because I just enter an id,
here is the code :

task :

```
namespace :geocodeschool do

  desc "Show premium school near non-premium school and update them"

  task :schgc => :environment do

      @schools = School.all

      def premium_school_aside(school)
        radius = 50
        @schools_a = School.near(school.coordinates.reverse, radius, units: :km)
        @schools_premium = @schools_a.premium_school.limit(3)
      end

      @schools.each do |school|
        premium_school_aside(school)
        puts "// -------------- //"
        puts "AUTO-ÉCOLE : #{school.title}"
        puts "// -------------- //"
        puts "les auto-écoles premiums près de #{school.title} : #{@schools_premium.count}"
        puts "-------"

        @schools_premium.each do |sa|
          puts sa.id
          school.update(school_premium_asides: sa.id)
        end

        puts "-------"

    end

  end

end
```

and the field in the model :

```
  field :school_premium_asides, type: Array
```

Does someone could explain me why, and how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in your model:

```
field :school_premium_asides, type: Array
```

so Mongoid is expecting to see arrays when you assign to `school_premium_asides`. But then in your rake task you have:

```
school.update(school_premium_asides: sa.id)
```

and presumably `sa.id` is a single `BSON::ObjectId` value. That means that you're trying to write a single `BSON::ObjectId` to a field of type Array and that's where your:

> Value of type BSON::ObjectId cannot be written to a field of type Array

error comes from.

I'm not certain what your code is trying to do but I think you want to assign all the `id`s of the `@schools_premium` to the `school_premium_asides` field in `school`. If so then you want to replace this:

```
@schools_premium.each do |sa|
    puts sa.id
    school.update(school_premium_asides: sa.id)
end
```

with:

```
school.update(school_premium_asides: @schools_premium.map(&:id))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ! I think you have understand what I wanted to do, but I want to puts in the Array the 3 nearest premium school, to display them on view, that's why I created an Array, to fill it with the 3 id's, is it more clear ?

Comment: You just have to find the three closest and then `school.update(school_premium_asides: those_three_ids_in_an_array)`, right?

Comment: but I have this following code : `@schools_premium.each do |sa|
          puts sa.id
          school.update(school_premium_asides: sa.id)
        end`  it should work, no ?

Comment: No because `sa.id` is not an array but `school_premium_asides` is supposed to be an array. `update(school_premium_asides: [ sa.id ])` would "work" but wouldn't do the right thing.

Comment: Ok I understand, but how can I do to loop on all school, and insert in array only 3 nearest schools for each school ? with `school.update(school_premium_asides: @schools_premium.map(&:id))` the array is going to be filled with all premium school, isn't it ?

Comment: Okay it work, you were right ! but I have now a problem, why I can't access to the BSON Object ? if I try to, I juste have the id on the view, I can't use `@school.title`, do you know why ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about your code to be able to answer those questions. Your question is just about the "Value of type BSON::ObjectId cannot be written to a field of type Array" error, perhaps you need to ask more questions about the other issues.